# Rails don't render layout when create record with Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, nomethoderror

My problem is after I create a new record with ajax I get a NOMETHODERROR and I must reload the page to see the new record.

The Error I get in terminal.

> Rendered time_entries/_time_entry.html.erb (3.4ms)   Rendered
>   time_entries/create.js.erb (4.9ms) Completed 500 Internal Server Error
>   in 41ms (ActiveRecord: 4.4ms)
>
> NoMethodError - undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass:
>   app/views/time_entries/_time_entry.html.erb:1:in '_app_views_time_entries__time_entry_html_erb___4086905375499854267_70174828432680'

What I do wrong?

**time_entries_controller.erb**

```
class TimeEntriesController < ApplicationController

  ...

  respond_to :html, :js

  def index
    @time_entries = current_user.time_entries.all.order("date DESC")
    @time_entries_days = @time_entries.group_by{ |t| t.date.beginning_of_day }
    respond_with(@time_entry)
  end

  def create
    @time_entry = TimeEntry.new(timeentry_params)
    @time_entry.user_id = current_user.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @time_entry.save
        format.html { redirect_to @time_entry, notice: 'Arbeitszeit wurde eingetragen' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @time_entry }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @time_entry.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.js
      end
    end

  end

  ...
```

**_time_entry.html.erb**
the partial

```
<% @time_entries_days.each do |day, time_entries| %>
    <% if day.today? %>
        <div class="column-12 list-group">Today, <%= l day, format: :dm %></div>
    <% else %>
        <div class="column-12 list-group"><%= l day, format: :dm %></div>
    <% end %>

    <ul class="lists">
      <% time_entries.each do |time_entry| %>
        <li class="list-item" id="time_entry_<%= time_entry.id %>">
          <div class="list-item__content">
            <h3 class="list-item__title">
              <%= link_to time_entry.category.name, time_entry %>
              <span><%= l time_entry.start_time, format: :hm %></span> - <span><%= l time_entry.end_time, format: :hm %></span>
            </h3>
            <p><%= time_entry.note %></p>
          </div>
          <span class="list-item__label"><%= time_entry.hours %>h</span>
        </li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
<% end %>
```

**index.html.erb**

```
  <% if can? :create, TimeEntry %>
      <%= link_to 'Add new Time Entry', new_time_entry_path, remote: true, class: 'btn btn-primary', :data => { :'popup-open' => 'popup-1' } %>
  <% end %>

  ...

  <div class="row" id="container_time_entries">
    <%= render "time_entry" %>
  </div>
```

**create.js.erb** for testing
I don't get an alert after I create a new time entry.

```
alert("HALLO");
```

**create.js.erb** normal

```
$('.modal-bg').hide();
$('.popup').fadeOut(350);
$('#container_time_entries').html("<%= j(render 'time_entry') %>");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not set the variable `@time_entries_days` in your create method, but you need it in your _time_entry.html.erb .

Set it and you should be good to go.

Comment: But now I can see the new record without refresh the page after I create another record. I